# How do I use sort function for a Date Array?

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

I have this array:

```
let arraRisultati = DataManager.shared.storage.filter { $0.Data < NSDate() as Date }
```

Can I order its elements in chronological order with the "sort" function?

Comment: You posted a bad attempt to use a filter. Where's your attempt at sorting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you want to get only elements whose date is prior to now, it would be better to pick up the current date just once, and you can do it directly as a `Date`:

```
let now = Date()
let arraRisultati = DataManager.shared.storage.filter { $0.date < now }
```

Since `Date` is `Comparable`, you can sort on it like this:

```
let sortedResults = arraRisultati.sorted(by: { $0.date < $1.date })
```

You can do it in one expression if you prefer:

```
let now = Date()
let arraRisultati = DataManager.shared.storage.filter({ $0.date < now }).sorted(by: { $0.date < $1.date })
```